who is the current Assignee/Owner of US12019694B1
https://patents.google.com/patent/US12019694B1/en?inventor=Maxim+Cheremkhin

There is contradiction in the header and the sequence of Assignees. According to the sequence, the Assignee is Citibank NA?

Sorry I said BofA in comment on other question. It’s confusing enough without my error.

Go to the USPTO assignment link on this google patent search page and you will see the CitiBank recordation is not an assignment but the recordation of a security interest. Commonly done to secure a line of credit.
Also, the U.S. does not require recordation of assignments until some court action is about to occur so the true assignee at any moment is not definitely publicly known.
